# Execute solidity contract methods from specific account on Ethereum Remix JavaScript VM

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, remix

I currently make a test contract on ethereum.remix.org.
But how can I specify the account in the test file from which a contract call should be sent?

```
contract test {
    MyContract contract;


address creator = address(0);
address payable account2 = address(1);
address payable account3 = address(2);
address payable account4 = address(3);

function beforeAll () public {
   contract = new MyContract();
}

function makeCallFromAccount2 () {
    contract.function1(10);
}
}
```

How can I specify that contract.function1(10) is executed from account 2?
(This is important because the contract method uses the msg.sender value)

Answer (score -2):

Apparently you can do this though there is little documentation on how to use:
https://github.com/ethereum/remix/tree/master/remix-tests#use-a-different-sender-msgsender

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to switch the accounts inside a test contract, so that method1 is executed from account 1 and method2 is executed from account 4 for example.
You are of course right I can switch the accounts on the GUI manually and execute the contract method call manually, but I want to write a test contract which can switch the accounts inside the test file /contract.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that you were wanting to do this inside a test contract.

Looks like you can do it, though the documentation doesn't have a lot of details.